# Creating instances of different class types in a function

Tags: java, spring, powermockito

While building a unit test, I'm struggling with the correct way of trying to achieve the follow:
I'd like to have a function that receives Varargs of Class, and will have the ability to instantiate each of the given classes.
It's something like this:

```
    public static void mockContextBeans(Class<?>... classes) throws Exception{
      for (Class<?> c : classes){
          when(context.getBean(c)).thenReturn(c.newInstance());
      }
    }
```

Can someone please point me to the correct way achieving it?

Thanks

Comment: This looks  an awful lot like you're trying to mock Spring - don't do that. Spring provides are powerful and complete [system for testing Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing-introduction.html). Don't try and rewrite yourself, either you will fail or it will take you several months of development time.

Comment: As stated in your reference:
_The POJOs that make up your application should be testable in JUnit or TestNG tests, with objects simply instantiated using the new operator, without Spring or any other container. You can use mock objects (in conjunction with other valuable testing techniques) to test your code in isolation._

This is what I'm trying to achieve, I have parts in the code where there are lines like: "context.getBean(...)" , and i'd like to mock them.
assume that I can't change the production code.

Comment: _"I have parts in the code where there are lines like: `context.getBean(...)`_" - eugh. There's your problem right there. Your code **isn't** unit testable as you have fallen into the classic Spring anti-pattern of using `ApplicationContext` as an all purpose magic factory. If you **ever** need to inject `ApplicationContext` into a bean, step back and think of another way.

Comment: I know it's "eugh", but sometimes you don't get to choose the production code of the new company you just got into.
So, back to the question, let's not relate to the "eughs" in my code, and assume that I want to understand it for the purpose of knowing the correct way to do what I wanted to... can you please assist?

Comment: As I said above, it's not unit testable - use the spring integration testing framework. Spin up a test context with the `@ContextConfiguration`, and set up `@Configuration` classes that create your mocks. I know of no other way - trying to manually mock Spring is a deep rabbit hole I would avoid like the plague. Tests will be fragile and subject to breaking with new versions of Spring.

Comment: Your problem with the above code is that (using a degenerate example) `context.getBean(List.class)` will retrieve a previously registered `ArrayList`. Your code will not do that. It will try and do `List.newInstance` - which will fail for obvious reasons. One registers bean _instances_ in the context but retrieves them by _`interface`_ - so your approach simply cannot work.

Comment: What do you mean it's not unit testable? it surely works if I do it for one class: i.e:
`when(context.getBean(SessionUtils.class)).thenReturn(new SessionUtils());`

So, why shouldn't it work for multiple classes? I'm just missing something in the way of writing this correctly.

Comment: Why on earth is your code calling `getBean` with the **actual implementation class**?? Run away, run away very fast.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm kinda new to spring, and was asked to start making unit tests for some classes, which lead me here.
so I don't know why and if it's correct or not to use getBean and how, and it doesn't really matter for the sake of the question.
But let's just assume that it's not spring that i'm using, and getBean() is actually "getSomething(..)" which returns <?> ?.
How on earth can I mock the behavior I wanted in the first place?

Comment: "What do you mean it's not unit testable?" He means it's not unit testable. There're other way of phrasing the statement - for instance, code smell.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Hey, I understand you're in great pain of reading the bad practice that my company's code uses.
But if you could just stick to the real question asked, and not relate to the surrounding context it will be much appreciated. please refer to my last comment as to what really is interesting me in this thread.

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) as to why your code doesn't work. See my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994391/creating-instances-of-different-class-types-in-a-function?noredirect=1#comment76963751_44994654) for what you need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting against the way Spring is supposed to be used, but if you really need to make that work you probably could say `....thenReturn(Mockito.mock(c))`. Mockito shouldn't care what kinds of constructors exist on the classes.

Comment: I suppose you then need to know what behaviour of the mock to mock. The current approach (doesn't work, but if it did...) solves that by using real instances so they behave as they should. It's certainly possible to add a giant case switch and add the behaviour, or add an answer service, but it all begins to get complicated quickly.

Comment: when trying to go with this approach i get the following error: 
_Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#2-of ? to capture#1-of ?_